# Multiple Videos on one page that are anchors, how do I stop the anchor covering the controls of the videos?

Tags: html, video, controls, anchor

I have one page of videos that are anchors to each other on the page. So if you click on the first video it slides down to the next and so on. However, because they are anchors the controls can not be clicked on. How can I get around this problem?

this is the page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/djangolive_1.html

Thanks for any help.

Angela

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

HTML:

```
<li>
<a href="#"></a>
<video></video>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li { position: relative; }
li a { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 640; height: 33px; }
li video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

This way, the a tag will overlay the video, but not the player controls at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work as there are multilple videos, they end up being layered on top of each other.

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to have to controls outside of the video, so you wouldn't need to click on the video itself?

Comment: As long as you set relative positioning to the li's, and set any margins you have on those li's instead of the video tags, then you should be fine.

Comment: I think if the li's also had the same width as the video elements, you would be all set